# JavaFX label and button

Tags: java, button, javafx, label

```
public class Controller {
    public Label Lsd;
    public Label Lsm;
    public Label Lsc;
    public static Label L1 ;
    public static Label L2;
    public static Label L3 ;
    public static Label L4 ;
    public static Label L5 ;
    public static Label L6 ;
    public static Label L7;
    public static Label L8 ;
    public static Label L9 ;

    public Button B1 ;
    public Button B2 = new Button();


    public void clcL1(Event event) {

        if (L1.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 1;
        }

    }

    public void clcL2(Event event) {
        if (L2.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 2;
        }
    }

    public void clcL3(Event event) {
        if (L3.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 3;
        }
    }

    public void clcL4(Event event) {
        if (L4.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 4;
        }
    }

    public void clcL5(Event event) {
        if (L5.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 5;
        }
    }

    public void clcL6(Event event) {
        if (L6.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 6;
        }
    }

    public void clcL7(Event event) {
        if (L7.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 7;
        }
    }

    public void clcL8(Event event) {

        if (L8.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 8;
        }
    }

    public void clcL9(Event event) {
        if (L9.getText().equals(" ")) {
            MakeMove.clickedLabel = 9;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void clcB1(Event event) {
        B1=new Button();
        checkEmpty();
        Engine.makeTable(Engine.board, Engine.board1);
        MakeMove.play();
    }

    @FXML
    public void clcB2(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        checkEmpty();


    }


    void checkEmpty() {

        if (!L1.getText().isEmpty() && !L2.getText().isEmpty() && !L3.getText().isEmpty() &&
                !L4.getText().isEmpty() && !L5.getText().isEmpty() && !L6.getText().isEmpty() &&
                !L7.getText().isEmpty() && !L8.getText().isEmpty() && !L9.getText().isEmpty()) {

            L1.setText(" ");
            L2.setText(" ");
            L3.setText(" ");
            L4.setText(" ");
            L5.setText(" ");
            L6.setText(" ");
            L7.setText(" ");
            L8.setText(" ");
            L9.setText(" ");

        }

    }

}
```

Error message when I click on B1:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7544 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1250 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Mario\OneDrive\Java\Projekti\out\production\Projekti;D:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain sample.Main
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$102/677100880.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/858826413.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.checkEmpty(Controller.java:109)
    at sample.Controller.clcB1(Controller.java:93)
    ... 43 more
```

This application needs to be GUI tic tac toe, but when I click to button which only need to set all labels text to " " i get this message. I think that problem is with Event handler,but im not sure. It is my first ''biggest'' project with javaFX and I need help. If you need another code from project, tell me and i will upload. Thanks

Comment: Where are you creating those L1 to L9 labels? If you don't assign a value, you get a NullPointerException

Comment: public static Label L1 = new Label() ; when I do this for all labels and click on button  which need to set some text on all label, nothing happening.. I forgot to say that I built GU with JavaFX scene builder.

Comment: I removed static from public static Label.. and I think it will work. thanks @James_D